# How to render and display imge from nodejs to rect js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-hooks

[I get the image from the user in form of formdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX4ym.png)
[This is how I made the Schema of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng1QY.png)
[The Image is successfully  in Monogodb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyBsP.png)
[This is how I fetch information of images by Axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WP0en.png) 
[I write code from rendering the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQbhd.png)
[This is how my wesite look when image is not been render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0ZRn.png)

[I

Proper image on wesite

Proper image on wesite

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

where you are rendring the image using btoa method, this method is not present or deprecated in your framework, that's why you need to add that

first add -

```
var Base64 = new function() {
        var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="
        this.encode = function(input) {
          var output = "";
          var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
          var i = 0;
          input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);
          while (i < input.length) {
            chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
            enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
            enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
            enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
            enc4 = chr3 & 63;
            if (isNaN(chr2)) {
              enc3 = enc4 = 64;
            } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
              enc4 = 64;
            }
            output = output + keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
          }
          return output;
        }

        this.decode = function(input) {
          var output = "";
          var chr1, chr2, chr3;
          var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
          var i = 0;
          input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
          while (i < input.length) {
            enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
            chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
            chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
            chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
            output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
            if (enc3 != 64) {
              output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
            }
            if (enc4 != 64) {
              output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
            }
          }
          output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);
          return output;
        }

        this._utf8_encode = function(string) {
          string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
          var utftext = "";
          for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {
            var c = string.charCodeAt(n);
            if (c < 128) {
              utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
            } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
              utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
              utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            } else {
              utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
              utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
              utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
            }
          }
          return utftext;
        }

        this._utf8_decode = function(utftext) {
          var string = "";
          var i = 0;
          var c = 0,
            c1 = 0,
            c2 = 0,
            c3 = 0;
          while (i < utftext.length) {
            c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);
            if (c < 128) {
              string += String.fromCharCode(c);
              i++;
            } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
              c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
              string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
              i += 2;
            } else {
              c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
              c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
              string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
              i += 3;
            }
          }
          return string;
        }
      }()
```

And then to create a function

```
var btoa = Base64.encode;
```

now you can use your Code or

```
var image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa('your-binary-data');
<img src={image}/>
```

Comment: Now working  but the image data is coming

Comment: could you please more elaborate